# Mock IConfiguration's GetChildren() to return List<string>?

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I need to mock `IConfiguration` for the following `appsettings.json` values.

```
{
  "a": 0.01,
  "b": [ "xxx", "yyy" ],
}
```

However, the following code gets error on `b.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns(new List<string> { "xxx", "yyy" });`.

```
var configuration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();

var a= new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
a.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns("0.01");

var b = new Mock<IConfigurationSection>();
b.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns(new List<string> { "xxx", "yyy" }); // Error

configuration.Setup(x => x.GetSection("a")).Returns(a.Object);
configuration.Setup(x => x.GetSection("b")).Returns(b.Object);
```

Error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'

## Update:

I tried to change the error line to:

```
b.Setup(x => x.GetChildren()).Returns(new List<string> { "xxx", "yyy" } as IEnumerable<string>);
```

Now the error is

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection>'
```

Comment: What is the data type of `IConfigurationSection.Value`?  I'm guessing its `string`?

Comment: `string`. How to mock the return values of `GetChildren()`?

Comment: Yes appsettings is a string. A json string, specifically. You are trying to return a `List<string>` where `Value` is just a `string`, not a collection of strings. You need a JSON parser if you want it to return the individual fields. Can you post the real code where you are using `IConfiguration.Value`? It will make it easier to help you setup the mocks for test if we know what you're using in your actual code.

Comment: @JoshWilliard, the code which uses it is `_configuration.GetSection("b")?.GetChildren()....`

Comment: Why are you trying to Mock this just make one with the values you want in it...

Comment: You should make an in memory fake configuration. If you did Mock it, you would want to return the JSON representation of the list for `Value` (`"[\"xxx\", \"yyy\"]"`) instead of a concrete list to work with the various `Get` extensions.

Comment: @johnny5, I thought mocking was the only way. I will try the approach in the answer.

Comment: @ca9163d9 Do the setups on the actual methods you want to use. Much easier that way. Your setup would look like this `mocksect.Setup(ms => ms.GetSection(It.Is<string>(s => s == "b")).GetChildren())
    .Returns(new List<IConfigurationSection>(){//sectionshere});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration module is independent and allows for the creation an in memory configuration to test against without the need to mock.

```
//Arrange
Dictionary<string, string> inMemorySettings =
    new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"a", "0.01"},
        {"b:0", "xxx"},
        {"b:1", "yyy"}
    };

IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(inMemorySettings)
    .Build();

//Verify expected configuraton
configuration.GetSection("a").Get<double>().Should().Be(0.01d);
configuration.GetSection("b").Get<List<string>>().Should().NotBeEmpty();

//...
```

#### Reference [Memory Configuration Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#memory-configuration-provider)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you may want to read configuration from a json string converted into a stream. That just looks a bit fancy imo and gives more flexibility when testing complex configurations:

```
public static class ConfigurationHelper
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{\"Root\":{\"Section\": { ... }}");
        using var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonStream(stream)
            .Build();
    }
}
```